# Efficient Server Backup

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I have a Hyper-V server (Windows Server 2012) running 8 virtual servers.

What is the most efficient method of backing up my servers so that if one needs to be restored, I am able to restore the server quickly?

It would be great if I could restore the server state (e.g. by doing a bare-metal backup) instead of having to reinstall the OS, joining the domain and adding roles and restoring the data manually.

I like Azure's backup service and I have a local NAS that can be used for storage.  However, when I create a bare-metal backup, it saves a lot of unnecessary data.  For instance, one of my servers is running IIS ARR as a reverse proxy.  Theoretically, I would think that I could do a bare-metal backup of this server with a file the size of a small text file (List of roles, users, domain information and IIS configuration). Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use Windows Server Backup.
2. Windows Server Backup doesn't save "a lot of unnecessary data", it saves everything that is required to perform a bare metal restore if you perform a Full Server backup or a backup that has the bare metal recovery option selected. If you don't want the backup to save everything that is required to perform a bare metal restore then a bare metal backup is not what you're looking for.
3. You can't have your cake and eat it too. If you want a backup that will let you recover the server in the quickest, most efficient manner then a Full Server backup or a backup that has the bare metal recovery option selected is what you need. If you want to pick and choose what gets backed up then a Full Server backup or a backup that has the bare metal recovery option selected is not what you need and you'll have to resort to rebuilding the server and installing the Roles and Features that you want and then restoring the data that you backed up.

Comment: I guess that is just what I will have to do!  It just seems as though you could create backups of a bunch of servers and have all of the system files saved once instead of repeated in every backup -